# Idea: show questions that link to the current question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, related-questions

Either in the related questions list (with very high weighting) or in a separate list, it would be useful to show questions that link into the currently-viewed question.

Comment: That's neat. <<15 char filler>>

Comment: This would be a nice feature.  It helps when looking for an answer, and will reduce the duplicate questions!

Comment: would you also include links from comments?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to seeing posts that link to other posts, it might also be useful to see external links and/or search terms. I have several posts that, for whatever reason, seem to get a steady stream of upvotes and I'd like to know how people are finding them.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. I was about to post a request to support linking questions together as a form of "follow-up questions" but decided that it would be overly complicated for something so simple (or, if you like: it breaks the KISS principle.)

Your suggestion is more intuitive though.